# Get value of option in Select - HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code :

```
<select id="Negrillon">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Couleurs</option>
    <option value="#588c75" data-class="color-588c75">#588c75</option>
    <option value="#b0c47f" data-class="color-b0c47f">#b0c47f</option>
    <option value="#f3e395" data-class="color-f3e395">#f3e395</option>
    <option value="#f3ae73" data-class="color-f3ae73">#f3ae73</option>
    <option value="#da645a" data-class="color-da645a">#da645a</option>
</select>
```

And i would get the option value in JavaScript. I tried this but it's doesn't work. If you can help me, it's very cool.

```
var e = document.getElementById("Negrillon");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: If you want value, then try `var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value`.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/actgl2o8c90sf3h/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202015-03-19%2023.33.42.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

You should use this :

```
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```